# Reducing tcp segment size in a pcap file

Tags: tcp, pcap, segments

tcprewrite can fragment packets at the IP level, is there a tool for splitting tcp segments at the TCP level resulting in more smaller sized segments?

Comment: Make up your mind what you're asking about. TCP segment size is determined by the sender. Fragmentation is determined by the sender and intermediate routers. At capture time it's all too late.

Comment: What would be the expected output regarding SEQ / ACK numbers and window sizes? Artificially recompute all this? Maybe this is an X/Y question. What are you really trying to do to achieve which goal?

Comment: I'm asking about an existing packet capture, not at capture time. I would like to have its data converted to small sized chunks, not smaller packets rather smaller segments at the TCP level. As stated, tcprewrite is able to split a pcap to smaller sized data chunks, I'm looking for a tool that would do so but on the Transport level. SEQ/ACK # would be computed by the tool apropos the defined segment size and ensuing number of segments.